# jQuery link with rollover box

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, hover

i have a div which when you rollover gives some info on the div you're rolling over, along with some links inside... how do I allow for the div to have a hover, yet allow the link inside to be clickable

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Is this some sort of tooltip functionality? Many of the rich tooltip plugins for jQuery support HTML (incl. links).

Answer (score 0):

if you use [Jquery.cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/) you can do it.

you can set the popup position

```
topOffset:     
leftOffset:
```

Comment: Cool thanks, will have a look, I'm hoping it allows the tip to appear over the top of the link